# Note-taking software like "Notational Velocity" for Linux

Tags: linux, software-rec, notes

Is there a Linux equivalent of the note-taking software [Notational Velocity](http://notational.net/)?

Comment: Can you describe what features of that app you like?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek It shows you all txt files or a folder (e.g. your docs) in a list, and you can easily search through them. There is no open/save. Every edit will save immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[NVpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nvpy) is "a cross-platform simplenote-syncing note-taking app inspired by Notational Velocity."

Looking at screenshots NVpy looks like a closer match than TomBoy.

[image: nvpy screenshot]

Here's a little [write-up of NVpy on Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5938721/nvpy-brings-notational-velocity-style-note-taking-to-all-platforms).

Though [this guy didn't like it](http://blog.nikhilism.com/2012/11/a-poor-mans-notational-velocity-on-linux.html) and tweaked gvim a bit instead.

Looking more, I found [NVVim](https://github.com/cwoac/nvvim) which "is a clone of the mac app Notational Velocity in vim. It is designed for fast plain-text note-taking and retrieval."

[image]

Comment: About 10 years later and this may all be irrelevant thanks to https://obsidian.md/

Answer (score 1):

[TomBoy](http://projects.gnome.org/tomboy/index.html) is a note taking application for linux, which is probably the closest thing to Notational Velocity currently available.

Comment: Or try [Gnote](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Gnote) if you don't want the overhead of Mono/.NET

Answer (score 1):

As a vim user, I've been meaning to try out SoyWiki: http://danielchoi.com/software/soywiki.html

Answer (score 1):

The [Zim Desktop Wiki](http://zim-wiki.org/) is a note taking software written in python.
There are many extensions available for zim (LaTeX formulas or music scores...).

It is available in the [official tree of most Linux distributions](https://repology.org/metapackage/zim/versions) already.

[image: zim-wiki]